# Managing multiple dependencies in Angular JS jasmine testing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a pretty simply filter which builds URLs for my templates:

```
angular.module('deAdmin.filters.shiurViewLink', []).filter('shiurViewLink', ['configService', function(configService) {
    return function(shiur) {
        if (shiur == null)
            return "#";

        return configService.getAppRoot() + "/shiurim/" + shiur.id + "/";
    }
}]);
```

The referenced `configService`:

```
angular.module('deAdmin.services.configService', []).factory('configService', [function() {
    var service = {};

    service.getAppRoot = function() {
        return "/admin";
    };

    service.getStaticPrefix = function() {
        return "/static/admin";
    }

    return service;
}]);
```

Here is my test for the filter:

```
'use strict';

describe('shiurViewLink', function() {
    var $filter, filter;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('deAdmin.filters.shiurViewLink');
        inject(function($injector) {
            $filter = $injector.get('$filter');
            filter = $filter('shiurViewLink');
        });
    });

    it("should properly generate the shiur view link", function() {
        expect(filter({ id: "abcdefg" })).toBe('/admin/');
    });
});
```

I'm seeing the following error in Karma/Jasmine test run:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: configServiceProvider <- configService <- shiurViewLinkFilter
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.4/$injector/unpr?p0=configServiceProvider%20%3C-%20configService%20%3C-%20shiurViewLinkFilter
    at /home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:12
    at /home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3479:19
    at Object.getService [as get] (/home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3606:39)
    at /home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3484:45
    at getService (/home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3606:39)
    at Object.invoke (/home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3628:13)
    at /home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3485:37
    at Object.getService [as get] (/home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3606:39)
    at /home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular/angular.js:13687:24
    at /home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/test/js/admin/filters/shiur-view-link-test.js:10:22
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2086:25)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/test/js/admin/filters/shiur-view-link-test.js:8:9)
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/naftuli/Documents/Work/PyCharm/rtshiurim/test/js/admin/filters/shiur-view-link-test.js:15:16)
```

How are dependencies handled in Jasmine tests? It seems like it can't find my service, though I'm fairly sure that the service is being imported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `configService` module should have `deAdmin.services.configService` as a module dependency since `configService` and `shiurViewLink` are in different modules.

```
angular.module('deAdmin.filters.shiurViewLink', ['deAdmin.services.configService']).filter('shiurViewLink', ['configService', function(configService) {
    return function(shiur) {
        if (shiur == null)
            return "#";

        return configService.getAppRoot() + "/shiurim/" + shiur.id + "/";
    }
}]);
```